# 3 year old no longer interested in bedtime stories

Tags: reading

Recently we moved across the country. Prior to this, my daughter always loved bedtime stories and we read three stories every night. Her grandma got her a "nabi" that she's now grown to love. She no longer wants me to read her stories before bed because she says the nabi has storybooks that read to her. It hurts my feelings a bit as this was our special time, and I don't think it's good for her to be watching that before bed. But at the same time they are just stories with interactive pictures. Is this normal? I've tried making funny crazy voices to make it more fun but she tells me that I can read to myself! Lol :( any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Hi and welcome. That would make me sad as well. What, may I ask, is a "nabi"?

Comment: @anongoodnurse [Nabi tablet](https://www.nabitablet.com/)

Comment: Have you set up rules for the Nabi-Tablet yet? When and how long she can use it? If she plain cannot have the Nabi in the evening (yep, she'll be angry at first, but push through!), I doubt she'll fight having that special time with you again.

Answer (score 3):

### Put limits around the Nabi

It's good to start early with limiting technology.

Let me be clear here: I'm a great proponent of technology for children - my career and hobbies are both heavily technology dependent and I wouldn't be where I am in life without the computers lying around the house when I was a child... however, there must be limits. As much as anything else, the blue light from the screen will play havoc with your child's sleeping pattern, and the "active" videos don't encourage settling into bedtime.

Along with the light issue, there's also the obvious point that watching videos (while not intrinsically a bad thing) doesn't encourage reading: reading is vital to comprehension, writing, and analytical skills later in life, and should be encouraged wherever possible. Similarly the social aspect is important.

As such I suggest limiting the Nabi: eg it can be used from *some time of your choosing* until *2/3 hours before bedtime* for example... or can be used for 1 hour after each meal, if she's well behaved during the meal. Whatever you feel works well for you.

### However

An important note, though, is that during this process you should **separate taking away the Nabi, from the return to reading**. Whatever you do, **do not** associate *"You have to come off the Nabi so we can read"* as a concept: you don't want your child to see reading as a punishment taking her away from what she wants to do.

Instead limit the Nabi for a few weeks, then re-introduce reading once she's stopped wanting the tablet at bedtime (there will be some resistance, 3 year olds are stubborn as I'm sure you're aware! Wait until that resistance subsides). Allow them to be separate events.